# Using Aptana Studio for Extendscript

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting, aptana, extendscript, content-assist

I've been using Sublime Text for creating the Javascript flavor of Extendscript scripts for our company. However, I've been curious about Aptana Studio and whether or not it might be a better choice to move to it. Already, however, I can see two big issues:

- Handling Extendscript-specific code
- Content assist using a DOM.

In the regular versions of Eclipse, if I wanted to use a specific piece of code from a library and get content assistance with it, I'd just add its `.jar` file to my build path and I was done. However, Javascript doesn't seem to use libraries, per se, so how would I get it to know the various methods and properties of a `TextField` object when I use the ol' <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> after typing in a reference to one, followed by a dot?

And at the beginning of my scripts, I have to use preprocessor directives, such as:

```
#target indesign;
#targetengine session;
```

so that the script knows what program I am using, if I want to `#include` other files, etc. These commands are, of course, specific to Extendscript, so when Aptana sees them, it breaks the Javascript syntax highlighting for the rest of the document. Is there any way to set Aptana to, perhaps, ignore preprocessor directives? Or add their syntax into its rules checking for syntax highlighting?

Comment: Have you considered Brackets ? It has ExtendScript code auto-completion ;)

Comment: I just gave it a try. Very nice editor. However, it appears to do the same thing as Sublime Text in that it only knows the built-in Javascript properties & methods, plus any properties & methods that you've already called elsewhere in the script.  
  
e.g., if I've never used `Document.loadSwatches` in my script, Brackets won't tell me that it's available when I start type `Document.`. In addition, when I load up my existing script, it brings up JSLint errors on those two `#target` lines I mentioned in the question.

Comment: I discovered the correct name for the `#target` lines and edited the post to reflect that they are actually "Preprocessor Directives".

Answer (score 0):

Also consider the [ExtendScript Toolkit](https://creative.adobe.com/products/estk), if you haven't tried it yet.  While it's not as powerful an editor, it does know about some of the DOM functions, and it has convenient built-in debugging tools for working with CC applications.

Comment: I've used it some, but I'll admit I haven't really given it a whole lot of attention. What primarily turns me away from ExtendScript Toolkit is its lack of syntax highlighting and code completion. And I'm still a newb about the debugging tools, such as setting breakpoints, what "step into" and "step over" mean, etc. The only times I find myself needing ExtendScript Toolkit anymore are when I just need to test a few lines of JS code relatively quickly.